# How to return to view for ConfirmEmail using Web Api Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

User after register page, it will send confirmation email to user's email ID by following code

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }
        #region Added Code for Send Email

        string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
        code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
        try
        {
            string callbackUrl = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Account/ConfirmEmail", userId = user.Id, code = code });
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        #endregion
        return Ok();
    }
```

Then the user will receive the email

[image: Email picture]

Then when user click the picture, it is going to call the **confirmEmail method of AccountController api**

```
[Route("ConfirmEmail")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        code = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code);
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        return Ok(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "ErrorEmail");
    }
```

it is returning like below image.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">ConfirmEmail</string>
```

**Note**

> I want to display on the view page. I don't want to display like this.
>
> Can I do redirect to another controller view, if the result is succeeded?.

Comment: In your `ConfirmEmail()` method, instead of passing that condition, why not call the controller that will return the view that you want instead? `return Ok(HomeController.EmailConfirmed());`

Comment: Or, have the email link route to a controller ActionResult method that will return the view. so when they click the link, instead of calling an apicontroller, it's going to call a the controller. and within that controller, prior to returning View it can call that apicontroller to perform that logic. then if true, return ok  in apicontroller and then return view in controller